# How Can One Tell The Difference Between The Spiritual Mind And The Physical Mind?

Tags: consciousness

Is there any information in the texts that tell you the difference between the spiritual mind and the physical mind. I know there are ways to transcend, but that's not what I'm looking for. What I'm asking is complicated. At what is a thought or action created by the physical mind/brain, and when is a thought or action created by the spiritual mind, or super-consciousness, or whatever. Or, are all thoughts/action created by the mind?

Comment: What do you mean by "spiritual mind, or super-consciousness, or whatever?" Is it something like Jung's collective unconscious? Maybe god, or gods or something else? Can you explain it better?

Answer (score 5):

There are other sources that support the notion that there is only one mind or consciousness in all that is. Here is one such source

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buddhism_and_the_body

> In contrast with many Indian religious traditions, Buddhism does not
>   regard the body and the mind or spirit as being two entirely separate
>   entities- there is no sense in Buddhism that the body is a "vessel"
>   that is guided or inhabited by the mind or spirit.[1] Rather, the body
>   and mind combine and interact in a complex way to constitute an
>   individual. Buddhist attitudes towards the body itself are complex,
>   combining the distaste for sensual pleasure that characterizes the
>   general Buddhist view towards desire with a recognition of both the
>   individuals dependence on the body, and the utility of the body as an
>   aide in the development of insight.

Roshi Suzuki has given lectures to American students teaching what is beginner's mind. It might be of interest. 
www.arvindguptatoys.com/arvindgupta/zenmind.pdf

When thoughts stop, there is nothing but sweet nothingness.

Answer (score 4):

There's no physical mind. Brain is Rupa(matter). There are only 2 aspects to the universe.

- [Nama](http://www.budsas.org/ebud/whatbudbeliev/73.htm) - mental aspect
- [Rupa](http://www.budsas.org/ebud/whatbudbeliev/73.htm) - physical aspect

These 2 are further subdivided into five groups called the [Panchaskanda](http://www.beyondthenet.net/dhamma/fiveAggregates.htm)(five aggregates)

Usually what we call as thoughts belong to the [Sankhara](http://www.beyondthenet.net/dhamma/formations.htm) group. Thoughts are caused by both physical and mental causes.

Answer (score 1):

I practice with the [Triratna Buddhist community](https://thebuddhistcentre.com/text/what-triratna-buddhist-community) and we have a notion of the reactive mind and the creative mind. The reactive mind is small and governed by habitual responses. The creative mind is big and can respond to situations in a more positive and open way. With practice we can access the creative mind however even then the reactive mind will be there but as a part of this greater whole. There is a [lecture](http://www.freebuddhistaudio.com/talks/details?num=31) about this or some [lecture notes](http://www.freebuddhistaudio.com/texts/lecturetexts/031_Mind_Reactive_and_Creative.pdf) if you prefer.

From the lecture notes - the reactive mind is..

> [..] also a repetitive mind. The reactive mind tends to do the same
>   thing over and over and over again. That’s another reason why it’s
>   like a machine. It gets the same stimuli - the same old newspaper
>   open, the same weather or whatever it may be

while the creative mind is

> [...] active on its own account. The motive power, the force, the
>   drive, the inspiration, as it were, of the creative mind, comes from
>   the depths within the mind itself. Not just from external stimuli.

I personally find this way of thinking moderately useful however it can lead one down the path pf a very goal orientated and grasping practice if not taken in the right spirit. Also it's interesting to note that this concept was nicked from the Scientologists who, i think it's fair to say, have a mixed reputation as a spiritual community.

Answer (score 0):

There is no such thing as a physical mind. The mind has no form, color, size, smell, etc.
The brain is the organ that controls the body.
A thought is always a mental process originated in the mind. Once a thougth arises it can create an emotion and from that comes the "motion" or action. 
The mind control the brain and the brain controls the body.

Comment: This is based on what?